# How to make extension method which should returns generic type but only nullable numeric datatype in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods

I have created one extension method for datarow which is like this, it can return primitive type only.

```
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToNullableNumber(Of T As Structure)(dataRow As DataRow, columnName As String) As T
        Dim result As T
        Dim isNumebr As Boolean = IsNumber(dataRow, columnName)

        result = If(isNumebr, dataRow(columnName), 0)

        Return result
    End Function
```

calling it like

```
Dim drUplodedFileRowas as DataRow = dataTableCustomer.Rows(0)
Dim paidAmount as Integer = drUplodedFileRow.ToNullableNumber(Of Integer)("PaidAmount")
```

this is fine for non nullable type but I want to call my ext. method like this also

```
Dim paidAmount as Integer? = drUplodedFileRow.ToNullableNumber(Of Integer?)("PaidAmount")
```

but it is giving error.
**"system.nullable does not satisfy the 'structure' constraint for type parameter 'T'  only  non-nullable ''Structure' types are allowed"**

then I called it like this which also giving same error

```
Dim paidAmount as Nullable(Of Integer) = drUplodedFileRow.ToNullableNumber(Of Nullable(Of Integer))("PaidAmount")
```

can any one explain me how do I define my extension method so it should accept primitive nullable data type also.

Comment: "but it is giving error" is *never* enough information.

Comment: Have you tried Nullable(T) to return nullable values? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SureshKumarVeluswamy, yes I called it like that also that does not help

Comment: I suspect you should actually make your method return `Nullable(Of T)` instead of `T` - so you'd call `ToNullableNumber(Of Integer)`.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud check for DBNULL and return Nothing.
Here is a sample:

```
Sub Main()

        Dim table As DataTable
        table = MakeTable()

        Dim dr As DataRow = table.NewRow
        'dr("NullIntValue") = 
        dr("NotNullIntValue") = 5

        ' value1 = 5
        Dim value1 As Integer = dr.ToNullableNumber(Of Integer)("NotNullIntValue")

        ' value2 = Nothing
        Dim value2 As Integer? = dr.ToNullableNumber(Of Integer)("NullIntValue")

    End Sub
```

And:

```
Module StringExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function ToNullableNumber(Of T As Structure)(dataRow As DataRow, columnName As String) As Nullable(Of T)
        Dim result As T

        If IsDBNull(dataRow(columnName)) Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Dim isNumebr As Boolean = IsNumber(dataRow, columnName)
            result = If(isNumebr, dataRow(columnName), 0)
            Return result
        End If

    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function IsNumber(dataRow As DataRow, columnName As String) As Boolean

        Dim result As Int64
        Dim str As String = CType(DataRow(columnName), String)

        Return Int64.TryParse(str, result)

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Even if I return nothing, value of nullable variable give "0" . Dim value2 As Integer? = dr.ToNullableNumber(Of Integer)("NullIntValue")